Disable the feed in chat
IMO the question feed in chat isn't really useful and drowns out the rare chat messages. So I'd prefer to disable it.
Does anybody want to keep it? If not, could a diamond please disable it?

I'm not a fan of the feed, although this isn't very important given just how quiet the chat is!

@figlesquidge I think it contributes to the chat being quit.

Years ago (is it really already two and one-quarter year?), we added the main site question feed to the chat to get notice of new questions, and also to be easily able to discuss them in the chat, if necessary.
A month later I added the meta question feed bot.
Back then we had maybe two or three questions a day, so it didn't disturb any chatting which might have been going on.
Later we got more questions and less chat, and nowadays it looks like it is only a feed, with once a while an unanswered chat message.
So, I'm going turning the main question feed off right now. I'm letting the meta feed on for now, as these questions might create some discussion.
Actually, I found that there is the option to have a different type of feed, which shows the messages at the top instead of posting them persistently into the chat. Let's see if that works.

I used to like the question feed because it was a way to find out passively about new questions. That was before there were live updates on the sites, though. Now I don't particularly care for question feeds, and indeed I prefer to have a few feeds containing posts that merit special attention, such as bounties. (For example, on [french.se], we have a feed for questions tagged french on [english.se] — I don't think the equivalent would work here though, as a feed of questions tagged cryptography on other sites would be overwhelming.)
I don't hang out in the Crypto chat because most people who hang out on the Crypto site and on Stack Exchange chat tend to hang out in the Security Stack Exchange main chatroom.

The "cryptography" tag doesn't look that overwhelming to me -- I'm counting about 50 questions tagged across the network in the last week (mostly on SO, with a few on math.SE).  That's less than our own question volume here. The real firehose is "encryption", though.

I tend to agree. 
Whenever I check the chat to see if anyone has posted anything new over there, I notice the minimal amount of chat-posts practically “drowns” in the feed's overkill.
If we want more people to join in on Crypto.SE, we need to do our best to look as “inviting” as possible. And indeed, pushing the same questions into a user’s face in multiple sections of the site (including the chat) might not really be the most productive thing to do when thinking in terms of “user-experience”.
Thinking… wasn't that feed in the chat introduced so that our crypto-chatroom doesn't auto-freeze? If, we would definitely need more chat activity to prevent auto-freezing as soon as that feed is disabled. 
Maybe a "weekly meeting" (or something like that) could bring some more activity into the chat? I bet we all agree it's currently awfully quiet around there and not really “inviting” to anyone, while the embedded feed might practically close the door from a new-user point of view. Something tells me we can do better. After all, we are Crypto.SE — surviving 878 days in beta (and counting)!

Actually, the feed didn't help against the auto-freezing (and that was certainly not the reason). It originated in the time we rarely had new questions (and when some regular users always had the chat running to be informed about new questions). That was when I still had much more free time :-)
